# How i can show notification on android after check php

Tags: java, php, android, eclipse, notifications

I have a *php*.. Somebody will be login in **my application** by **webview**.
And android application must check **www.website.com/notification.php** every 5 seconds.

```
 if notification php ==> echo 1 ; .. show notification.
 if notification php ==> echo 0 ; .. dont do anything..
```

I want to check 0 or 1  value by android..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute your network code in `AsynchTask`, dedicated `thread` or `IntentService`, here is an example code:

```
Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.website.com/notification.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());

        if("1".equals(result.trim()){
            showNotification(); // You have to implement this
        }
    }
}
networkThread.start();
```

Be aware, that making a network request every 5 seconds will drain the battery so quickly, because it will keep the GSM/3G active *all* the time.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I dont have any idea about AsynchTask, dedicated thread or IntentService, .. How can i use that code i dont know..

Comment: I made a quick edit to the code to use a dedicated `Thread` which is the easiest of the three.

Comment: **Be aware, that making a network request every 5 seconds will drain the battery so quickly, because it will keep the GSM/3G active all the time.** but i wondered, whatsapp also working in everysecond?

Comment: Maybe when it is in the foreground and the user actively using it, but I would strongly suspect they can do this in the background